# Can not get onion services to serve tor website

Tags: tor

I am running Onion services on Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on an old iMac with 10.0.0.8 ipaddress. I also installed nginx and can access the static page from my laptop so clearly the nginx setup is correct. I can access the static page locally and across the LAN. HTTP://10.0.0.8

I installed Tor using the directions from the official tor website.

I edited these two files
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80

The local admin user on the iMac is "imac", imac user is in the group debian-tor. However I can't seem to use

When I run the tor status this is the output. Everything looks good.

```
imac@imac-iMac:~$ sudo service tor status
tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sat 2024-03-23 23:10:12 EDT; 9s ago
    Process: 3643 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 3643 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1ms

Mar 23 23:10:12 imac-iMac systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
Mar 23 23:10:12 imac-iMac systemd[1]: Finished Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
```

When I try to access the site via onion service tor address created in the host file the tor browser returns this error.
https://jhj2pdlhtahsxcest4zoy7b6l2pvtk3r5bdioeqpte4s5dxdeee6ffad.onion/

```
"The requested onion service descriptor can't be found on the hashring and therefore the service is not reachable by the client."
```

I just feel like I am doing something stupid. I disabled UFW. Is it possible that XFinity is blocking something?